# String.Format line break

Tags: vb.net

i have a simple statement of code that reads:

```
Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", _var1, _var2, _var3)
```

i'm trying to get this formatted string to output each var on it's own line. i'm new to vb.net but i did try one thing:

```
"{0}\n {1}\n {2}"
```

that didn't work. any help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this:

```
Return String.Format( _
    "{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}", _
    Environment.NewLine, _
    _var1, _
    _var2, _
    _var3 _
)
```

This could work too, though it's a bit "trickier":

```
Return New StringBuilder() _
    .AppendLine(_var1.ToString()) _
    .AppendLine(_var2.ToString()) _
    .AppendLine(_var3.ToString()) _
    .ToString()
```

Comment: I would use your first example.  Also you don't need to `ToString()` each variable for `AppendLine()`

Comment: @Pondidum: Well, `StringBuilder.AppendLine` takes a `String` argument, so as long as the OP has `Option Strict On` he'll need to call `ToString` unless the three variables are already of type `String` (which wasn't indicated).

Comment: Ah, i was looking at `Append()` not `AppendLine()`

Comment: Best of Both: 

`Return New StringBuilder().AppendFormat("{1}{0}{2}{0}{3}{0}", _
    Environment.NewLine, _var1, _var2, _var3 ).ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like

```
String.Format("{1}{0},{2}{0},{3}{0}", vbcrlf, _var1, _var2, var2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function sformat([string], ParamArray args()) As String
    [string] = [string].replace("\n", vbLf)
    [string] = [string].replace("\r", vbCr)
    Return String.Format([string], args)
End Function
```

use like you would use string.format except call sformat(yourstring, param1, param2)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
Return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",_var1 & vbcrlf, _var2 & vbcrlf, _var3 & vbcrlf)
```

Comment: all those repeated vbcrlf and concats seem to miss the point of string.format

Comment: this really isn't bad, IMO. it makes sense to me rather than to have tons of substitutions to look up to keep the line feed syntaxes together for each linefeed "phrase".

Answer (score 0):

OK  So VB is lame in this regard.   How about this:

String.Format("Var1: {0}\nVar2: {1}\nVar3: {2}".Replace("\n", vbCrLf), var1, var2, var3)

Answer (score 0):

This also works using xml literal for the format string

```
        Dim fmt = _
<xml>Var 1: {0}
Var 2: {1}
Var 3: {2}</xml>
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format(fmt.Value, 1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
return $"{_var1}
{_var2}
{_var3}"
```

Or alternatively:

```
return $"{_var1}{vbCrlf}{_var2}{vbCrlf}{_var3}"
```

Do ensure that you are on one of the more current VB implementations.